# Access an element based on its child class

Tags: css

I have the following HTML

```
<div class="class1">
    <div class="class2">
    <div class="class3 subclass1">
        Test
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

and I need to add the CSS:

```
background-color: yellow;
```

to the `div` with class `class1` that has a child div with class `class3 subclass1`. Cannot just add the CSS to the `class1` as there could be more than one `div` with class of `class1`. 
Is that possible with just CSS?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to style of a parent using only CSS, you'll have to use JS.

https://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/css-parent-selectors goes into a bit of detail on why this doesn't (and probably won't) exist.